# iReport 5.0.0 - How to display percentage inside each pieslice

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I'm trying to create a pie chart in iReport 5 where the percentage of each slice of the pie is displayed inside the pie chart. The closest I have come to this is to show the percentage outside the pie chart. I have also tried to use a customizer class. What would I need to add to make the pie chart display some text or the percentages inside each pie slice as the below picture shows?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [jfree.org](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/images/PiePlotSample.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do this by adding this to the Customizer class:

```
Plot plot = chart.getPlot();
PiePlot piePlot = (PiePlot)plot;
piePlot.setLegendLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{2}"));
piePlot.setSimpleLabels(Boolean.TRUE);
```

I consider this the solution for the problem.

Comment: Is this code showing percentage inside individual slice?